# ZKTime Web cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, zkteco

I installed Xampp and lauchd the Apache and MySQL services. After that, while installing the ZKTIME + WEB 2.0 and configuring the server to connect to MySQL DB, it says **Unknown Error**
Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to OLD version DB then please note that Old and New version DB schemas are different. I am getting same error.

If you try to connect after installation through WDMS server Management. Connection will be made but the WEB portal won't work because of schema difference.